# How can I center align title-bar text in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Is there any way (built-in, or 3rd-party app) to change the title-bar text to be center-aligned like it was in Windows 8?

Comment: It looks like you want the opposite of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/542495/how-can-i-left-align-title-bar-text-in-windows-8 The answer would be the same though, 3rd party software. Ironically enough, WindowsBlinds would probably be your best bet in this case too.

Comment: WindowBlinds is listed as incompatible with Windows 10 http://forums.wincustomize.com/469524

Comment: Hmm, guess we'll have to wait then. I remember people got it working during the Preview, but it'll be safer to wait for a real release.